# Obter permissão para gravar no Cartão SD no Android 6+

Tags: android, android-permission

Estou criando um app que lê e grava arquivos no Android, acontece que não consigo permissão para gravar no armazenamento externo do dispositivo.
Depois de pesquisar vi que preciso chamar essa tela para obter a permissão, mas não sei como chama lá.
[image: Pedido de permissão em tempo de execução]

[image: Aparentemente um OpenFile padrão do Marshmallow]

[image: Selecionando o armazenamento externo (Cartão SD)]

[image: Permitendo acesso ao App para gravação no Cartão SD]

Essas imagens encontrei na Web e também já vi apps como o Word ou esFileExplorer pedindo.

Então estou pedindo as permissões de escrita e leitura externa no OnCreate da minha MainActivity desta maneira:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{
                                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Para ler arquivos tanto do emulated/0/sdcard/ (armazenamento interno) quanto no /mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/ (armazenamento externo (Cartão SD instalado no dispositivo)) consigo carregar minha o arquivo para a minha aplicação

Agora para escrever é um pouco mais complicado, em emulated/0/sdcard/ até consigo, mas em /mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/ dá um exception, veja:

> E/TAG: /mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta
>   Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission
>   denied)

Meu código para escrita esta logo abaixo

```
FileOutputStream outputStream;
    File file = new File("/mnt/media_rw/C4B3_13EE/Pasta Pessoal/Documentos/TextoSaída.txt");
    try {
        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        outputStream.write(textView.getText().toString().getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
        Log.e("TAG", file.getAbsolutePath() + " Arquivo Criado");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("TAG", file.getAbsolutePath() + " Arquivo NÃO Criado");
        Log.e("TAG", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
}
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this,new String[] {file.getAbsolutePath()}, null, null);
```

Comment: Você só precisa pedir a permissão em tempo de execução, use a lib ReactivePermissions de Max Cruz: https://github.com/MaxCruz/reactive_permissions.

Comment: Essa lib só pede as permissões. Eu estou pedindo as permissões. o Problema é que realmente dá Permission denied

Comment: Para termos a certeza de que o problema é das "permissões em tempo de execução", no dispositivo em **definições** -> **aplicações** escolha o seu aplicativo  e atribuas manualmente.

Comment: Feito. O switch do Armazenamento esta habilitado

Comment: O erro continua?

Comment: Sim. Já estava habilitado antes. Minha aplicação pede as permissões em tempo de execução corretamente.

Comment: Vou reabrir a pergunta. O problema tem outra causa. A pastas no sdcard foram criadas pela sua aplicação?

Comment: Ok, parece que consegui encontrar um meio de gravar, usando o Storage Access Framework, vou pesquisar mais um pouco e testar e se resolver o problema respondo

Answer (score 1):

Bom, foi bem difícil mas consegui. Descobri que na versão 4.4 (Kitkat) do android foi introduzida um SAF (Estrutura de Acesso ao Armazanamento), no site do android developer explicar melhor e tem os snippets que usei para solucionar parte do meu problema, vejam:

1. Estava usando o intent ACTION_GET_CONTENT (que obtêm uma cópia do arquivo desejado), para obter o arquivo que desejava editar, no entanto o google aconselha a usar o ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, se quero ter um acesso persistente (Criar, em caso de pasta, editar, deletar), mesmo em Cartão SD.

Com isso feito, me apareceu outro desafio, quando salvo o arquivo editado, o bloco de notas do windows não "vê" as quebras de linhas que colocamos no android. Para resolver essa questão fiz esse pequeno código:

```
String texto = textView.getText().toString();
String separador = "\n";
String[] linhas = texto.split(separador);
```

Com cada linha obtida na hora de escrever apenas modifiquei um pouco o snippet da seção Edição de um documento, colocando um foreach:

```
for (String linha : linhas)
    fileOutputStream.write((linha + "\r\n").getBytes());
```

Assim o bloco de notas nativo do Windows, consegue ler cada linha individualmente.

Observação: Caso você faça alguma alteração em algum arquivo enquanto o dispositivo android estiver conectado em modo MTP, você deve remove-lo (ou alternar para apenas carregando) e voltar a liga-lo ao computador. Mesmo procedimento vale para Linux (pelo menos no Ubuntu 16 precisei realizar).

Fontes:
 https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html?hl=pt-br
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11247253/extract-a-line-from-an-edittext